# NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM crash on windows 10

Tags: boot, bsod, windows-10

I cannot boot into windows because I get a crash the error code was 
NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM or something like that. Please help.

Comment: after several failed boot, you should get recovery options. Now select the command prompt and run **chkdsk C: /r /f** to detect a corrupted filesystem .

Comment: Never mind, I got my computer fixed. Had to reinstall Windows 10.

Comment: I got my pc fixed, works as normal. Had to reinstall windows 10.